# Remove a rogue Custom Action Script Link

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, sharepoint-addin, custom-actions

I have been testing out a JavaScript Custom Action add-in  injected a test script into my SharePoint Online master page. During one of the change and deploy cycles this seems to have gone awry as a previous version of my Script Action has gone rogue (One!).  I can't remove this older Script Action which means the script.js fires always, regardless of if I add or remove the current version of the Add-in

```
   • [ScriptLink] {41d1c22d-9b4e-4eb9-aaa4-ed66683e938b} ScriptSrc=null Sequence=0
```

Any ideas how to nuke this instance please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

probably needs improving but can help in stressful situations

you can adapt the match as per your situation

```
    public void DeleteUserAction()
    {
        context = new ClientContext("http://contoso.com");
        context.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("user", "pwd", "dom");
        Web web = context.Web;

        context.Load(web, x => x.UserCustomActions);
        context.ExecuteQuery();

        List<UserCustomAction> ualist = new List<UserCustomAction>();
        foreach (var ca in web.UserCustomActions)
        {
            if (ca.ScriptSrc != null && ca.ScriptSrc.Contains("tweakviews.js"))
            {
                ualist.Add(ca);
            }
        }

        foreach (var aa in ualist)
        {
            aa.DeleteObject();
        }

        context.ExecuteQuery();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks very much , I might covert your CSOM code to PowerShell for quickness, I think that should work.  Luckily I test on a Developer Site and not our main intranet ;-)

Comment: Thanks so much... as you helped me focus 
$scriptActions = Get-PnPCustomAction -Scope web
$scriptActions[0].Id

Guid                                
----                                
41d1c22d-9b4e-4eb9-aaa4-ed66683e938b
 $scriptActions[0].ScriptSrc
 $scriptActions[0].DeleteObject()